# Mounted a volume in Docker, but container and localhost changes are independent

Tags: docker

I think I may either be experiencing an error, or misunderstanding the way volumes work in Docker containers.

I am starting my image using the following command: `docker run --name Goku -ti -p 3000:3000 -v VSPM:/root/goku:rw ubuntu:goku`

`VSPM` is the local directory and I am wanting to mount it to `/root/goku` on the docker container. Well, it mounts just fine; however, if I create a new file within the container, that new file doesn't show on the localhost in the `VSPM` directory. The same vice versa -- if I create a new file on the host in that folder, nothing changes in the container's folder.

What am I doing wrong? I just simply want a shared folder between the host and the container. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: What is the full path of the local directory you want to mount? Try using that instead of just VSPM.

Comment: Interesting. That actually did the trick. I appreciate that!

Comment: Glad to hear! I’ve added it as an answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full file path of the local mounted drive instead of just `VSPM`.